# facebook is this feature exists?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook page

https://www.facebook.com/Best.Brain.Teasers

and my website

http://gpuzzles.com

I have read ob facebook link below
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

The Comments box lets people comment on content on your site using their Facebook profile and shows this activity to their friends in news feed. It also contains built-in moderation tools and special social relevance ranking.

can i link my facebook page with my website
i.e all comments posted on my fb page wall automatically come under my post on webiste/blog.

Comment: Interesting feature requirement by you but i really doubt if this feature exists

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting to Facebook fan page feed as user trough PHP SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020585/posting-to-facebook-fan-page-feed-as-user-trough-php-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

Just paste the below code in your website where you need to post. Just make sure your server is Curl enabled and edit the code to fit in your facebook id.

```
<ul>
<?php
//function to retrieve posts from facebook’s server
function loadFB($fbID){
$url="http://graph.facebook.com/".$fbID."/feed?limit=3";
//load and setup CURL
 $c = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//get data from facebook and decode JSON
 $page = json_decode(curl_exec($c));
//close the connection
 curl_close($c);
//return the data as an object
 return $page->data;
}

/* Change These Values */
// Your Facebook ID
$fbid = "YOUR_FB_ID";
// How many posts to show?
$fbLimit = 10;
// Your Timezone
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");


/* Dont Change */
// Variable used to count how many we’ve loaded
 $fbCount = 0;
// Call the function and get the posts from facebook
 $myPosts = loadFB($fbid);


//loop through all the posts we got from facebook
foreach($myPosts as $dPost){
//only show posts that are posted by the page admin
if($dPost->from->id==$fbid){
    //get the post date / time and convert to unix time
     $dTime = strtotime($dPost->created_time);
    //format the date / time into something human readable
    //if you want it formatted differently look up the php date function
     $myTime=date("M d Y h:ia",$dTime);
    ?>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo($dPost->message) . $myTime; ?></li>
    </ul>
    <?php
    //increment counter
     $fbCount++;
    //if we’ve outputted the number set above in fblimit we’re done
     if($fbCount >= $fbLimit) break;
}
}
?>
</ul>
```